# Rounded corners in javafx

Tags: javafx, rounded-corners, polyline

Is there any way to make polyline's corners rounded in javafx. I tried stroke line join but it did not work. I want to make corners like the thin line in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something for this?

Comment: The image does not look like a single shape, let alone a `Polyline`. Which part of the image are you refering to?

Comment: I mean the thin lines. I tried stroke line jon method like i said in the question but it did not work. I also tried use Path and ArcTo but i couldn't it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line join don't help here, since they control the behavior for 2 path elements that don't have the same direction at the point where the lines join. They don't modify the path elements themselves. You need to use `Path` instead.

`ArcTo` and `QuadCurveTo` provide you with options for creating round corners. Both look pretty similar. The following code let's you play around with distance from the corner where the curve starts a bit:

```
private Path arcPath(DoubleProperty distanceProperty) {
    MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(300, 300);

    // end the line at the given distance right of the intersection of the lines
    HLineTo lineTo1 = new HLineTo();
    lineTo1.xProperty().bind(distanceProperty.add(50));

    ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();

    // end the curve at the given distance above the intersection of the lines
    arcTo.setX(50);
    arcTo.yProperty().bind(distanceProperty.negate().add(300));

    // radius is equal to the distance
    arcTo.radiusXProperty().bind(distanceProperty);
    arcTo.radiusYProperty().bind(distanceProperty);

    arcTo.setSweepFlag(true);

    VLineTo lineTo2 = new VLineTo(50);
    return new Path(moveTo, lineTo1, arcTo, lineTo2);
}

private Path quadPath(DoubleProperty distanceProperty) {
    MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(300, 300);

    // end the line at the given distance right of the intersection of the lines
    HLineTo lineTo1 = new HLineTo();
    lineTo1.xProperty().bind(distanceProperty.add(50));

    QuadCurveTo curveTo = new QuadCurveTo();

    // control point at the location where the lines would intersect
    curveTo.setControlX(50);
    curveTo.setControlY(300);

    // end the curve at the given distance above the intersection of the lines
    curveTo.setX(50);
    curveTo.yProperty().bind(distanceProperty.negate().add(300));

    VLineTo lineTo2 = new VLineTo(50);
    return new Path(moveTo, lineTo1, curveTo, lineTo2);
}
```

```
Slider distanceSlider = new Slider(0, 250, 10);
Label label = new Label();
label.textProperty().bind(distanceSlider.valueProperty().asString("%.2f"));
HBox controls = new HBox(distanceSlider, label);

Path path1 = quadPath(distanceSlider.valueProperty());
Path path2 = arcPath(distanceSlider.valueProperty());

VBox root = new VBox(new HBox(new Pane(path1), new Pane(path2)), controls);
```